# How do I dynamically size my divs to occupy the maximum possible width?

Tags: css, html, css-float, stylesheet

I need to accomplish the following situation for the header of my website:
[image: explanation image]

So, the image in the middle needs to be centered and has a fixed width. On the left and right of that image are divs that should occupy the remaining space.

Of course I could use javascript to listen on screen-width changes, but as this construct represents the logo of the corporate identity, a js solution would be ugly as it would resize the divs only when the user stops dragging and not continuously while dragging.

Also note that the divs should never wrap, all 3 elements should always be on a horizontal line. If the screen size is 150px, the divs should have a width of 0px and only the image should be visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are those divs empty or there are elements inside of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to support IE8 I would use `display: table-cell`:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="outer">div</div>
    <div class="image">image</div>
    <div class="outer">div</div>
</div>
```

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
}

div.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/R68eQ/

Comment: I completely forgot about good old (bad) tables! Thank you for that

Answer (score 3):

use CSS3 `calc()` function

```
.left-div{
    width: calc((100% - 150px) / 2);
}
```

[Caniuse calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: Nice one thx! Didn't know about calc. Unfortunately it's not yet widely supported (Only 1% of Android users will support it)